# VBA Do Until Loop with Or "" condition

Tags: loops, excel, conditional-statements, vba

```
 Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Value = stringOne Or ""

        x = x + 1

 Loop
```

In the above VBA code slice, I get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. stringOne is declared a String. I can eliminate Or "" and the loop works. I can eliminate stringOne and only have "" and the loop works. Only when I add the Or "" does the loop stop functioning. I've even swapped order, i.e, = "" Or stringOne. Any thoughts?

Comment: It usually helps get answers if you include a tag for the language you're using. I'm suspecting either VBA or VB.Net, but it would help greatly if you would [edit] to include the proper language tag.

Comment: Why downvote OPs Q? It is a valid question and at least two people did understand it an posted a solution worth a +1 ?

Comment: Thank you Ken. Sorry, I am new to the forum as a poster and thought I had everything together. I edited to add VBA. I have worked on this one line of code for more than a full day and decided I needed outside help. I'm not sure why it's worth downvoting...my apologies for the offense. Please let me know what caused the downvote so I can learn from the mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any condition needs expressions and operators.

```
 Do until exp1 op exp2 OR exp3
```

might only be valid if `exp3` is a boolean type. "" (String) is not.

So it should be like

```
 Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Value = stringOne Or Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Value = ""
```

Comment: Works perfectly Axel! Thanks for the explanation. You have taught me something new today!

Answer (score 5):

You need a boolean operation after the OR, so you basically need:

```
Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Value = stringOne Or Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Value = ""

        x = x + 1

 Loop
```

Or "" is not a boolean operation, and therefore you have
`Do Until (boolean operation) OR (string constant)` instead of `Do Until (boolean operation) OR (boolean operation)`

Comment: Thanks Allan! I have no formal training in VBA and only learned out of necessity, so I am not familiar with the rules of the language, but it really helps me to know Or will require a boolean operation rather than a string. I'd upvote yours and Axel's responses, but I don't have any rep yet. You guys deserve the upvotes though!